# MySQL won't let me add a foreign key contstraint

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a foreign key like so, I am using MySQL Workbench, but I fail:

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`tr_role_menu_item` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_role`
FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_role`) REFERENCES `db_name`.`t_role` (`id_role`) ON
DELETE NO ACTION ON
UPDATE NO ACTION,
          ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_menu_item`
FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id_menu_item`) REFERENCES `db_name`.`t_menu_item` (`id_menu_item`) ON
DELETE NO ACTION ON
UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This is what Workbench outputs:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'db_name.#sql-659_c11' (errno: 150)
ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
ERROR 1050: Table 'tr_role_menu_item' already exists

SQL Statement:

CREATE TABLE `tr_role_menu_item` (

`id_role_menu_item` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`fk_id_role` int(11) NOT NULL,

`fk_id_menu_item` int(11) NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id_role_menu_item`),

 KEY `fk_role_idx` (`fk_id_role`),

 KEY `fk_menu_item_idx` (`fk_id_menu_item`)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Any Help Please?

Comment: Look at the links titled "Related" on the right side of this page.

Comment: I check a different post and altered the code like alter table tr_role_menu_item add constraint foreign key(fk_id_menu_item) references t_menu_item(id_menu_item) on update no action on delete no action; but it fails adding a second key